# Navigation applying class using jquery

Tags: jquery, css

I am having problems applying CSS using jQuery on navigation panel. When user clicks a link, the class .selected should get applied.

My html code is

```
 <ul id="example-two">
        <li><a href="#">About Us</a></li>
        <li><a href="#">Services</a></li>
        <li><a href="#">People</a></li>
        <li><a href="#">Career</a></li>
        <li><a href="#">Contact Us</a></li>
        <li><a href="#">Videos</a></li>
    </ul>
```

My CSS code is

```
#example-two li a { 
  position: relative; 
  z-index: 200;
  background-image: -moz-linear-gradient(#6C6C6C, #4A4A4A);
  border-radius:10px; 
  color: #FFF; 
  font-size: 14px; 
  display: block; 
  float: left; 
  padding: 6px 10px 4px 10px;
  text-decoration: none;
  text-transform: uppercase; 
}
#example-two li a:hover {
    background-image: -moz-linear-gradient(#ed2024, #c8171a);
    color: white; 
}

.selected{
    background-image: -moz-linear-gradient(#ed2024, #c8171a);
    color: white;
}
```

And my jQuery code is

```
<script>
$(document).ready(function() {
    $('ul#example-two li a').click(function() {
       $('ul#example-two li a').removeClass("selected");
       $(this).addClass("selected");
    });
})
</script>
```

Any idea, where am going wrong ?

Comment: There shouldn't be anything wrong with this. It must be an issue somewhere else. (Is this code actually being evaluated?)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You are overriding the background image value in your top CSS selector. See [here](http://www.vanseodesign.com/css/css-specificity-inheritance-cascaade/) for more info on css precedence.

Change `.selected` to `#example-two li a.selected`

http://jsfiddle.net/EuuhZ/1/

Comment: but there has to be something wrong somewhere..am unable to find it out

Comment: See edits. Note that your code will only work in FireFox. Is that intended?

Comment: no..i intend to make it work on all browsers.. where should i make the changes ?

Comment: @Jigar. The -moz specific background gradient will only work in FF. There are a bunch of sites that will generate the css for you. Like this one for instance: http://gradients.glrzad.com/

Comment: yes..i had figured it out..thanks.and code is working fine after making the changes u suggested in ur edits :)